# Adding Mosaic Raster into SDE

Tags: geotiff-tiff, enterprise-geodatabase, mosaic

I am georeferencing OS 25 and 50K TIFF images in ArcGIS Pro. I have created a raster dataset and use the mosaic tool to 'patch' all the SKs together.

The data has to sit within SDE to be able to feed Oracle, I know this is not best practice. I have tried both importing and simply copying into the SDE but it is not working. I also tried to publish as an image service but I don't have that function in ArcGIS Pro like I did in ArcMap.

I haven't done this in a long time and fear I have missed a simple yet crucial step.

Comment: The days of rasters in the database ended when ArcGIS Server started supporting caches at 9.0. I can't imagine how an Esri raster could "feed Oracle", but EGDB rasters haven't seen new development in ten releases. Since Pro uses new display and publishing engines, I'd have to wonder if this is supported at all.

Comment: Apologies this may be my mistake of not making it clear. We used the OS data to create a basemap within Uniform, oracle connects to the SDE database as the method to get the basemaps in. The mosaics were previously published as images and then added in to SDE in ArcMap but I cannot find the same function in pro to be able to save within the database like I did previosuly

Comment: It looks like this functionality was deprecated after 10.2, and is presently unsupported. You may need to contact Tech Support.